# Xcode 5 set code completion for new file type

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, code-completion, logos

I have been editing a lot of .xm files recently in Xcode. .xm is the file extension for a Logos iOS tweak, but has nearly identical code to Objective-c. My question is this: how can I make Xcode use objective-c code completions for .xm files? Currently it does not do this. I am using Xcode 5.1.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [iOS Open Dev](http://www.iosopendev.com/). It uses Xcode to build various jailbreak tweaks etc. I don't think it's possible to use code completion on any file in xcode, it has to be part of an XCode target. I've never set it up, but you could try the instructions [here](http://hiltmon.com/blog/2013/07/07/xcode-4-code-completion-for-external-build-projects/).

Comment: I have tried it before and don't like it very much.

Comment: What did you try? iOS Open Dev? Did you look at the other link?

Comment: Yes I have tried iOSOpenDev. I have read that link but I am using Xcode5 and this did not work for me :(